# Create a file that will fail when getting zipped

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, zip

I have a shell script that unzips an input directory of xml files into another directory, and then zips that directory. I am checking at each step if an error code is returned. I am looking for a scenario where the zip of the new folder with the xml files will fail. Here are the error codes for reference http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html

It seems like if the script gets to the point where it is about to zip the new folder without errors, then none of these could apply. Is it possible to create some kind of folder/file structure or type of file that will not be zipped successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially do this with `chmod` to deny access to the file:

```
$ touch file
$ chmod 000 file
$ zip file.zip file
  adding: file
zip warning: Permission denied
        zip warning: could not open for reading: file

zip warning: Not all files were readable
  files/entries read:  0 (0 bytes)  skipped:  1 (0 bytes)
```

(`zip` exits with error code 18)